# Lua ternary operator seeking for edge case

Tags: lua

Today I solve simple [The if function kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/the-if-function/train/lua) at the codewars. 
this kata if very simple, and it asks to implements `function` that works like ternary operator `bool ? f1() : f2()`.

I was very surprised that there was a hidden case when  `return bool and f1() or f2()` solution fails but `return (bool and f1 or f2)()` solutions
works.

What is the case of when `bool and f1() or f2()` works different with  `(bool and f1 or f2)()`?

Comment: AFAIK the expression you want to be using here is something like `bool and f1 or !bool and f2`.  Neither of what you wrote about is correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how it could be incorrect but works correctly and pass all tests?

Comment: The tests are obviously inadequate.

Comment: Chaining `and` and `or` is **not** equivalent to a ternary operator, even if they can be used to achieve the same result in many cases.

Comment: Do not add the solution to the question post; that belongs in answer posts below. I removed it from the post, please do not add it back in again.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. I just find and answer. **Impure function**
1. `true and a() or b()` fires a() if a() returns false then b() will be executed.
2. `(true and a or b)()` fires only a()
So in first case fires a() and b(), and both of them make their work.

```
local x = 0
function f1() x = x + 1 end
function f2() x = x + 1 end
-- this function fires both f1() and f2()
function if1(b,f1,f2) return b and f1() or f2() end 
-- x == 2

x = 0
-- this function fires only f1()
function if2(b,f1,f2) return (b and f1 or f2)() end
-- x == 1
```

Comment: In the 2. case, it only fires **a** function, because **a** is a not nil value, thus it is true, according to Lua. Since the `true and a` is true, this chunk will call `a()`. If **a** is nil  (the function or variable doesn't exist), this chunk would call `b()`. If both **a** and **b** function don't exist, the chunk will throw an error that you are trying to call a nil value.